# Python. Webkit. Browser. Открытие файлов

Tags: python, gtk, webkit

Задача реализовать браузер на webkit, который сможет открывать любые файлы. На данный момент мне удалось реализовать лишь открытие html.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2


def on_click(button):
    chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Open File", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN
    )
    chooser.add_buttons(
        Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
        Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
        Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
    )
    chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    if chooser.run() == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = chooser.get_filename()
        chooser.destroy()
        f = open(filename)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == '.html':
            webview.load_html(f.read())
    else:
        chooser.destroy()


win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_border_width(10)
win.set_default_size(400, 200)

hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
hb.set_show_close_button(True)
hb.props.title = "Browser"
win.set_titlebar(hb)

box = Gtk.HBox()
button = Gtk.Button(label="Open file")
button.connect("clicked", on_click)
box.add(button)
hb.pack_start(box)

webview = WebKit2.WebView()
win.add(webview)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

И была попытка реализовать открытие изображений.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2


def on_click(button):
    chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Open File", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN
    )
    chooser.add_buttons(
        Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
        Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
        Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
    )
    chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    if chooser.run() == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = chooser.get_filename()
        chooser.destroy()
        f = open(filename)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        pic_types = (
            '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.jfif', '.pjpeg', '.pjp',
            '.png', '.swg', '.webp'
            )


        image = Gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_file(filename)
        image.set_halign(Gtk.Align.START)
        image.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        overlay.add_overlay(image)
        win.add(overlay)

    else:
        chooser.destroy()


win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_border_width(10)
win.set_default_size(400, 200)

hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
hb.set_show_close_button(True)
hb.props.title = "Browser"
win.set_titlebar(hb)

box = Gtk.HBox()
button = Gtk.Button(label="Open file")
button.connect("clicked", on_click)
box.add(button)
hb.pack_start(box)

webview = WebKit2.WebView()
overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
overlay.add(webview)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Изображения не открываются, в чем может быть причина?
Каким образом реализовать открытие файлов любых расширений? Возможно, это можно сделать если использовать файл, помещенный в теги html страницы?

Answer (score 0):

На image не вызван метод show. В версии с браузером этот метод вызывается через `win.show_all()`.

Кстати webkit может открывать картинки и даже без тагов. лучше использовать метод load_uri в webview и get_uri в FileChooserDialog.